# How to get information about parameters

Tags: python, linux, scapy, kali-linux

Good afternoon. Please tell me how I can get information on each parameter of a package? For example, I look at what parameters the IP packet has:

```
ls(IP)
```

outcome:

```
version : BitField (4 bits) = (4)
ihl : BitField (4 bits) = (None)
tos : XByteField = (0)
len : ShortField = (None)
id : ShortField = (1)
flags : FlagsField (3 bits) = (<Flag 0 ()>)
frag : BitField (13 bits) = (0)
ttl : ByteField = (64)
proto : ByteEnumField = (0)
chksum : XShortField = (None)
src : SourceIPField = (None)
dst : DestIPField = (None)
options : PacketListField = ([])
```

My question is, how can I get information about the parameter ihl, tos, if, and so on... i.e., what can I specify in these parameters, what values a particular parameter supports?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list of all methods and fields in class

```
dir(IP)
```

but it doesn't gives details.

BTW: you can filter them as any other list

```
list(name for name in dir(IP) if 'raw' in name)
```

and it can be useful when you forgot some name and want to find it.

---

You can display information from docstrings in code

```
help(IP)

help(IP.ihl)
```

and it can gives some details.

---

And finally you can search in [documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and you find [scapy.layers.inet.IP](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.inet.html?highlight=IP#scapy.layers.inet.IP)

---

But probably to understand some fields you have to simply learn TPC/IP and other protocols which `scapy` only use - it doesn't decide how protocols are defined.

Comment: Thank you for the information and examples provided. I thought that in Scapy there is some information, for example, in the IP packet there is a parameter `len` and this parameter has values that it (the parameter) can take in some form, i.e. it has its own syntax of values for each parameter, and how they are set, with double quotes, single or without them at all.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. Use Python built-in function [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir).

```
from datetime import datetime

dir(datetime)
```

> ['**add**', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dir**', '**doc**',
>   '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**',
>   '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**',
>   '**ne**', '**new**', '**radd**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**',
>   '**repr**', '**rsub**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
>   '**sub**', '**subclasshook**', 'astimezone', 'combine', 'ctime',
>   'date', 'day', 'dst', 'fold', 'fromisocalendar', 'fromisoformat',
>   'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 'hour', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat',
>   'isoweekday', 'max', 'microsecond', 'min', 'minute', 'month', 'now',
>   'replace', 'resolution', 'second', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'time',
>   'timestamp', 'timetuple', 'timetz', 'today', 'toordinal', 'tzinfo',
>   'tzname', 'utcfromtimestamp', 'utcnow', 'utcoffset', 'utctimetuple',
>   'weekday', 'year']

Comment: To tell You the truth, I'm not very good at Python, to put it mildly.
Please give me an example.
Thanks.

Comment: @AlexRebell Python comes with a lot of built in functions , dir() is one of them. I'm importing datetime and them using dir as an attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.